# What are these used for

Tags: equipment

These metal tubes are open on one side and hang from the handle suggesting a frying use?[image]

Answer (score 2):

Could it be for frying a wrapped dough and pulling it out of the oil?

Comment: It does look like it could be a cannoli form, but I can't find any with a handle like that (although it would make perfect sense).